# error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it. - obs in java.util.Observable

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle, android-room, kapt

I just upgraded my android studio to Artic fox. And all of sudden I am facing an issue saying "error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it. - obs in java.util.Observable". It was working fine for the previous android version. Can any one help me please. I am stuck!! I tried every thing but did not work out.
Thanks in advance.

dependencies are as follows:

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.10"

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5'
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.2.5'
```

Comment: Are you using windows ?

Comment: Yes I am using windows 10